# Unable to connect remotely to mysql database hosted online

Tags: python, mysql, remote-access

I am trying to remotely connect to a mysql database from my company network, using the mysql.connector module in python. The db is hosted online (siteground.com).
*Error: Error while connecting to MYSQL 2003: Can't connect to MySQL server on.... (10061 no connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it)**

I have the correct hostname, username, password etc.., and have added my company's public IP address as an allowed remote access host.

I have been able to successfully connect using the exact same procedure from a python notebook hosted on google colaboratory (in google drive).

Any ideas on what the issue might be?
Thank you

Comment: Could be the Servers Firewall is rejecting you

Comment: Thank you, would that be the firewall on my end or the db host's end?  I am able to access the db remotely through a python notebook hosted elsewhere.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.